# TilesConfigurer throws NoClassDefFoundError on initialization

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, tiles2, apache-tiles

Problem: TilesConfigurer throws NoClassDefFoundError on initialization

Took steps to resolve:

- Import tiles jars.
- Added jstl.jar
- Added older vesions of tiles:
  tiles-api-2.0.6.jar
  tiles-core-2.0.6.jar
  tiles-jsp-2.0.6.jar
  tiles-servlet-2.1.2.jar
- Several restructuring of web deployments and ordering of imported jars.

**webmvc-context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <mvc:view-controller path="/jsp/index.jsp" />
    <mvc:view-controller path="/jsp/info/about.jsp" />

<bean id="tilesConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
        <property name="factoryClass"
            value="org.apache.struts.tiles.xmlDefinition.I18nFactorySet" />
        <property name="definitions">
            <list>
                <value>/WEB-INF/tiles-def.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>


    <bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
          p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
          p:suffix=".jsp" >
              <!--
             <property name="requestContextAttribute" value="requestContext"/>
             <property name="viewClass"
                value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles.TilesView"/>
                -->
     </bean>
</beans>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0" metadata-complete="true">

    <display-name>simple-tiles2</display-name>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring/web-application-context.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>tiles</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value></param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>tiles</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <filter>
    <filter-name>encoding-filter</filter-name>
      <filter-class>
        org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter
      </filter-class>
      <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
      </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>encoding-filter</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**Error Log Brief:**

```
13:26:51,622 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] (MSC service thread 1-1) Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@136d1b4: defining beans [org.springframework.web.servlet.config.viewControllerHandlerMapping,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter,tilesConfigurer,viewResolver]; root of factory hierarchy
13:26:51,627 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (MSC service thread 1-1) Context initialization failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tilesConfigurer' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/webmvc-context.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/servlet/view/tiles2/TilesConfigurer$SpringTilesInitializer
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1011) [spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:957) [spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:490) [spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461) [spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295) [spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223) [spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292) [spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) [spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:607) [spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932) [spring-context-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479) [spring-context-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:383) [spring-web-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283) [spring-web-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112) [spring-web-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3392) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3850) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895) [rt.jar:1.6.0_43]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918) [rt.jar:1.6.0_43]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_43]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/servlet/view/tiles2/TilesConfigurer$SpringTilesInitializer
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_43]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2398) [rt.jar:1.6.0_43]
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2708) [rt.jar:1.6.0_43]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:1987) [rt.jar:1.6.0_43]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:78) [spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1004) [spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer$SpringTilesInitializer from [Module "deployment.simple-tiles2-webapp.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:423)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
    ... 27 more
```

[image: First half of my jars.]

[image: Second half of my jars.]

I have used other versions of spring, but right now I am using 3.2.0.RELEASE.  Really appreciate the help.

Comment: I should have also said that this comes from the springbyexample tutorial.  http://www.springbyexample.org/examples/simple-tiles-spring-mvc-webapp.html

Comment: Which version of Spring are you using?

Comment: Can you post your pom.xml if you use maven or the list of jar you are using if you don't

Comment: I have made some edits to my question to give the clarifications you need.  I am using the 3.2.0.RELEASE version of spring and the libraries posted above.  Really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed two things in webmvc-context.xml.

```
<mvc:view-controller path="/index.html" view-name="index" />
<mvc:view-controller path="/about.html" view-name="info/index" />
```

and the tilesConfigurer and viewResolver beans

```
    <bean id="tilesConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
        <property name="definitions">
            <list>
                <value>/WEB-INF/tiles-defs/templates.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

   <bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass">
        <value>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView
        </value>
    </property>
   </bean>
```

There were also libraries that were changed. I don't think that is relevant, but here they are.

[image: Solution Libraries]